# making JVM send custom tcp-packet

Tags: tcp, jvm, code-injection

I'm playing a game and i'm trying to send some custom requests to the server in order to perform some tasks easier .. While i will gain little to none from this, i have become very interested in the educational part of it.

Since the game runs partially on client via a .jar and/or a .cab file i think it is run by JVM - correct me if im wrong
I have captured some traffic send by the game via wireshark. The protocol is TCP and it looks like this:
!, 1338,102,264,0.0 ,0.0,32433553,0, 102,264,
Nevermind all the numbers - thats for me to figure out.
But when i create and send a similar packet via a couple of different programs it always fails. This is of course because i am sending the wrong sequence number along with the TCP-packet.
So in order to not mess up the sequence-number i figure i will have to inject the process running the game and then somehow make it send my custom packets.

How do i go about that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't mess with the TCP sequence number in pure Java. Java doesn't even do that itself, the TCP stack does all that.

It is most unlikely that this is your real problem.